Visual Studio user secrets and Release build configuration
I am using Manage User Secrets in Visual Studio. This is fine. In my secrets file I have connection strings to local databases and settings to call locally running APIs. So when developing I am always working with local data and code.
Right now I want to try out the VS Performance Profiler but this should run with configuration of Release. If I understand user secrets, if I run the application in Release configuration it will pick up and use the standard appsettings.json, whcih I would prefer not to edit unless I have to.
Is it possible to let VS know that I want it to continue to use the secrets file, and therefore all my local settings, while running in Release?
